# Android: Ksoap2-android works on emulator (API 23) but not in tablet (API 19)

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to consume W3School testing web service, using ksoap2-android. Here's the code of my AsyncTask:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, SoapPrimitive> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pgdProgress.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected SoapPrimitive doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/FahrenheitToCelsius";
        String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/";
        String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("Fahrenheit", params[0]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try {
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            return (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TEST", "KSOAP2", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SoapPrimitive soapPrimitive) {
        pgdProgress.dismiss();
        if(soapPrimitive != null)
            txvOutput.setText(soapPrimitive.toString());
    }
}
```

It works on AVD emulator (API 23) but not on my tablet (API 19). Tablet's internet connection works because I can navigate through Google Chrome. Minimum SDK version of my App Project is API 15.

Log exception just throw this:

```
01-27 10:28:14.604 10437-10601/com.android.wsconsumer E/TEST: KSOAP2
```

Any ideas? Sorry for bad english, I hope you understand.

Comment: Surely there is more to the logcat.  Is the exception not shown below the "KSOAP2"?

Comment: @DeeV Nop, just that...